# Pull up your pants

Tags: grammar, phrases

Can we use "Pull Up" in the following context??
Suppose, there is a puddle and you need to pull something up from there.You have to go there and before that you need to raise the bottom of your pants to prevent them from getting wet by the puddle water.
Can we use "Pull up" to replace "Raise the bottom part" ?
After going through lots of sites it seems that "Pull up your pants" means to pull up your pants to avoid only showing your buttocks.
Note that, it's not about rolling up your pants.

Comment: You might "hike up your pants", though that may also mean pulling them up at the waist.  You pretty much have to add "legs" to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The correct phrase is

- Pull up your pant legs.

To avoid getting their pants wet from the puddle, they only need to pull up the *pant legs*, not the entire pants.

Comment: Though pulling up their pants is likely to have the same effect. In context, I think I’d be more likely just to say “Pull up your pants, you don’t want to get them wet in the puddle” or something like that—nobody would misunderstand unless they really wanted to. “Pull up your pant legs” sounds kind of like directions to a seamstress somehow.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned that he wanted an alternative to "pull up your pants".  Also, typically, one can pull up one's pants only a few inches, whereas if the legs aren't too tight, one could pull the pant legs up to the knee; much more useful for avoiding getting wet.

Answer (score 1):

If you were T.S. Eliot speaking for J. Alfred Prufrock, you might say

> I grow old … I grow old …
>
> I shall wear the bottoms of my trousers rolled.

But if you were someone else, you might refer to the same operation as "rolling up the cuffs of your pants" or (as Brian Hitchcock has already suggested) "rolling [or *pulling*] up your pant [or *pants*] legs."

As the various options suggest, there doesn't appear to be a single predominant way of describing the action—even if we restrict ourselves to the United States, where the article of clothing is likely to be termed *pants* rather than *trousers*.

Comment: In the context above, I think I'd be likely to say "You could get your trousers wet in the puddle", and leave it to the pants-wearer to decide what to do. : )

Answer (score 0):

Since the fashion trend of wearing the waistband of the trousers below the cheeks of the behind, "*pull up your pants*" is the go-to expression for telling someone to wear their pants correctly.

However, I think if you are trying to issue instructions to someone - to keep the hem of their pants from being soaked/soiled, (depending on what they are about to walk through) you could say ***"hike up your pants,"*** (or, better yet: **pant-legs**). As of yet, this expression has no racial overtones.

Comment: Sorry, Hot Licks - I guess we're on the same wavelength, but I type reeeaaallly slow.